# Как правильно проектировать компоненты?

Tags: javascript, проектирование

Надоело переписывать код в ходе разработки по несколько раз, поэтому хотелось научиться сначала проектировать/планировать, а затем реализовывать. Вот что я имею ввиду под этим.

Скажем у меня есть компонент кастомный селект. Я начинаю его делать и входе работы вспоминаю, что ведь нативных селектах можно стрелочки вверх/вниз клацать и значение меняется. Начинаю это добавлять в код, что-то переписывая. И т.д. А как хотелось бы?

Хотелось бы заранее понять какие переменные мне могут быть нужны (например, текущее значение селекта, значение option в фокусе), какие методы могут пригодиться и вообще как оно должно работать. А код писать уже глядя на то что получилось. Что-то меня тянет к конечным автоматам, но пока не пробовал.

Кто как решает эту проблему, кто какими инструментами пользуется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала продумываешь, что должно понадобится и делаешь что-то похожее. Сразу рассчитываешь на то, что менять это потом придётся. Как вариант, даже по мере реализации растаскиваешь всё на свои места. Но нельзя допускать кашу, из которой сложно что-то вытащить. Ну а изменение - это нормально. Я бы даже сказал, что это лучший способ получить что-то хорошее.

> Галерея, например. Ну разве нельзя спроектировать галерею?
>
> Или вы когда пишите подобные вещи то добавляете все на ходу:
>
> 1. добавили квадрат - это наша будущая галерея.
> 2. О, мне нужна стрелка вправо, добавляем элемент, обработчик
> 3. Ой, да мне ведь нужна переменная в которой будет храниться номер текущего слайда.
> 4. Наверное надо эту переменную при клике на стрелочку как-то изменять, (правим, ранее написанный код) и т.д.

Сначала надо продумать в общих чертах, что нужно.

1. Это галерея. В ней должны отображаться картинки. Одна из них активна.
2. Нужна возможность переключаться между слайдами.

Думаем, как мы хотим это получить. Вариант первый - что-то типа MVC с отделением логики от представления. Вариант второй - взаимодействие со скриптом минимально, скрипт не хранит состояние или хранит минимально необходимый для функционирования набор данных.

Я выбраю второй вариант. В соответствии с ним пункты выше превращаются в:

1. Активный слайд обладает классом `active`, остальные им не обладают.
2. Есть кнопки перехода со специальным значением, указывающим направление перемещения. Обработчик кнопок (один обработчик, не два!) убирает находит элемент с классом `active`, убирает этот класс и вешает на другой.

Собственно, это можно уже делать. Я специально ограничился этими вариантами, хотя, скорее всего, рассмотрел бы сразу на несколько шагов больше.

Добавляем требование:

3. Нужно автоматическое пролистывание слайдов.

Делаем:

3. Берём функцию обработчика события и выносим отдельно. Не меняем ничего, кроме остановки всплытия события, если она у нас была - она должна остаться в обработчике, а не в функции. Добавляем таймер, который вызывает ту же функцию, что обработчик, с параметром `"next"`.

Добавляем требование:

4. Нужен набор кнопок для переходов к конкретным слайдам (по кнопке на слайд).

Делаем:

4. Добавляем комплект кнопок с атрибутом, указывающим номер слдайда. В функции перехода к слайду помимо ключевых слов обрабатываем число. Если события были повешены как живые, то изменять обработчик не надо - всё заработает само.

Общая идея: на каждое действие я выношу какой-то нужный кусок кода, или добавляю какую-то функциональность. Изменений типа "а вот теперь тут в ста местах надо помеять одну строку" надо избегать. Для этого есть куча принципов, но вообще, все они сводятся к "избегать дублирования кода" и "не смешивать всё пв кашу - даже если обособленный в смысловом плане кусок кода находится в одной функции с ещё чем-то, он должен быть без излишних трудностей извлекаем из неё".

> Как-то это и происходит в моей жизни. Но я считаю этот способом не верным.

Нет, это как раз верный способ. Он чем-то похож на неверный, но на самом деле они различны. Заметь, каждое изменение требовало минимального изменения кода. Почти ничего кардинального не менялось как раз за счёт планирования архитектуры.

А вот неправильный способ:

1. Активный слайд позиционируется по контейнеру, остальные скрыты. Номер слайда храним в переменной.
2. Делаем две кнопки - вперёд и назад, каждая из них имеет свой обработчик, который скрывает все слайды и отображает нужный.
3. Добавляем таймер и копипастим в него код из обработчика кнопки вперёд.
4. Добавляем кнопки со страницами и вешаем на них обработчик. В очередной раз копипастим код, только теперь берём номер страницы из атрибута.

Почему этот способ фигня? И почему с каждым шагом он становился всё большей фигнёй?

1. На первом шаге мы предположили, что скрипт уже точно знает, что слайд занимает весь контейнер, а также способ его позиционирования там. Теперь это часть решения, мы не можем что-то поменять, не меняя код позиционирования слайда. Это ошибка. То, что может быть изменено независимо от нашей функциональности должно быть от неё как можно более независимо. Да, мы можем уаправлять скрытием и показом (хотя, такое решение потом тоже может стать отнюдь не лучшим, но тут уже в другом дело). Если мы можем легко отделить стилистику от функциональности, то мы так и должны поступить. Обращаю внимание на слово "легко" - если это отделение сложнее самой задачи, то нет смысла с ним возиться с самого начала, особенно если есть вероятность, что оно не понадобится. Но всё же надо помнить, что решений, заведомо препятствующие этому отделению, надо избегать.
2. У нас два обработчика, отличающиеся одним оператором: `++i` и `--i`. Причём, каждый из обработчиков делает достаточно много. Выше я говорил про изменение стилистики. Если оно тут понадобится, то придётся менять уже 2 места. А к четвёртому шагу - уже 4. Если даже предпположить, что мы по какой-то причине хотим иметь эти два обработчика, то ошибка в том, что мы не сделали отдельную функцию выбора слайда. Вместо этого мы продублировали её код. Кстати, такая функция помогла бы адекватно сделать и таймер. Да, в моём правильном решении такой функции нет, но там эта функция не требуется и при желании, в любой момент может быть вынесена с незначительным изменением кода.
3. А что будет, если я теперь захочу показ слайдов с анимацией? В этом решении придётся поменять 4 места, в которых надо жобавить анимацию. Если при этом всё же догадаться и вынести переход на слайд в функцию, то место будет одно. Но. Для добавления каждой анимации надо будет менять этот код. А что если я хочу использовать одинаковые анимации не только тут, но и в других местах? Возвращаемся к варианту с классом - там мы можем из другого места управлять анимацией. Мы можем просто добавить в разметке нужный класс элементу и всё будет работать. Максимальное изменение скрипта - это добавление бывшему активному элементу ещё одного класса и подписка на окончание анимации для его снятия. Всё.

> Должны быть способы описывать это более формально, в виде схем, графиков и т.д. Это мне и нужно.

Вот это не нужно. Это неправильный подход. Либо ты делаешь что-то для себя и точно знаешь, что должно получиться, и способен полностью продумать всю картину, или тебе придётся что-то менять по мере разработки.

На самом деле, даже если ты всё смог продумать, то, на мой взгляд, всё равно удобнее разрабатывать, постепенно приводя код к тому состоянию, которое ты задумал. Главное, не принимать решений, которые противоречат разделению.

> Ну и если вы расскажите о принципах, о которых упомянули, то было бы здорово.

- [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))
- [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))
- [GRASP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP)

Но это всё одни и те же идеи, которые дучше чувствовать на уровне того, какой вред нанесёт конкретное действие. На мой взгляд, не стоит цепляться за эти правила как за истину ради соблюдения самих правил. Главное понимать, что ты делаешь, зачем и к чему это приведёт.

Да, я тут ещё вспомнил. Код можно не только писать, но и генерировать. Это к вопросу о дублировании. Если известно, что будет нужен однотипный код, то можно не стараться всеми средствами избежать дублирования, а реализовать генерацию кода на основе сведений по различающимся местам. Что-то надо поменять? Меняем шаблон или генератор в одном месте и перегенерируем всё.

> Что-то меня тянет к конечным автоматам, но пока не пробовал.

Конечные автоматы - это весьма запутанные и странные структуры. Такой код, кроме некоторых случаев, будет очень сложно понимать и поддерживать. Единственный хороший вариант использования конечных автоматов - это их автогенерация на основе чего-то. Так уже делает компилятор C# с `yield` и `await`.

Comment: Ну вот мне не очень нравится вариант, что бы делать что-то похожее, а потом делать как надо. Потому что появляются какие-то не состыковки, которые часто приходится решать некрасиво или переписывать большую часть.

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus, обновил ответ. Не нравиться должно переделывать неправильное и вариант переписать всё. А вариант с доработками, но при адекватном коде, который не требуется переписывать, - это лучший вариант.

Comment: *приходится решать некрасиво или переписывать*. @psyсho_Octopus, не бойтесь рефакторить и переписывать. Это совершенно нормально.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Как-то это и происходит в моей жизни. Но я считаю этот способом не верным. Должны быть способы описывать это более формально, в виде схем, графиков и т.д. Это мне и нужно. Ну и если вы расскажите о принципах, о которых упомянули, то было бы здорово.

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus, ещё дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, наконец-то я получил развернутый и дельный ответ. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос странный. проблема не в инструментах. Проблема в том, что нельзя заранее угадать что вам понадобится при разработке.

Сама по себе разработка - это процесс принятия решений. Некоторые разработчики пытаются этого избежать, требуя "подробной спецификации". Или пытаясь "сначала все запланировать". Это не работает. Всегда будут непредвиденные изменения. Можно только минимизировать стоимость изменений. Поэтому феншуй для вас это:

- разделение представления и логики (angular/ko/whatever)
- юнит тесты (qunit?)

Comment: Видимо я сумбурно сформулировал вопрос раз всем он кажется не понятным. Хотя я в моем вопросе не вижу ничего странного и думаю, что рано или поздно многие к нему приходят. Это как проектирование БД, можно загуглить и увидеть много схем со стрелочками и прочим. Люди сначала проектируют все связи и потом реализуют (дополняя если надо по ходу). Я хочу тоже для интерфейсов. Научиться понимать заранее что мне может понадобиться для решения, а само решение уже дело 10-ое

Comment: @psyсho_Octopus Если бы проектирование "со стрелочками" работало - Agile как процесс разработки не был бы популярен. И TDD загнулось при рождении. Нельзя заранее все спроектировать. Нельзя спроектировать даже значительную часть (можно - но только для проектов, которыми никто не пользуется и в которых нет фидбека). Можно научится предугадывать некоторые вещи, но это зависит только от личного опыта.

Comment: Ну где, где я говорил про проекты?! Я говорю о маленьких компонентах, виджетах, если хотите. Галерея, например. Ну разве нельзя спроектировать галерею? Или вы когда пишите подобные вещи то добавляете все на ходу: 1. добавили квадрат - это наша будущая галерея. 2 - О, мне нужна стрелка вправо, добавляем элемент, обработчик 3. Ой, да мне ведь нужна переменная в которой будет храниться номер текущего слайда. 4. Наверное надо эту переменную при клике на стрелочку как-то изменять, (правим, ранее написанный код) и т.д.

Comment: Вот я и хочу научиться за ранее проектировать какие бдут события, состояния, как они будут взаимодействовать, что бы потом сесть и реализовать продуманный за ранее план.

Comment: *Ну разве нельзя спроектировать галерею?* Можно, но зачем "проектировать" столь маленький компонент? Напишите несколько раз галерею с разными ограничениями и у вас появится понимание, как ее писать. И так со всем. Нельзя просто захотеть и  научиться проектировать. Для этого нужен опыт и набитые шишки.

Comment: @PashaPash, TDD? во-первых, не очень то и загнулось, а во-вторых, совсем не поэтому. Оно как раз не предполагает продумывание, оно предполагает "написал тест - реализовал функциональность, перешёл к следующему случаю". Проблема в том, что современные IDE такое проектирование не поддерживают от слова никак. А то бы может все им спокойно пользовались и радовались бы жизни.

Comment: @Qwertiy предложение построено как "если бы ..." то "...". просто "бы" одного не хватает. нет там утверждения что tdd загнулось (по крайней мере я не это имел ввиду), и совсем не нужно мне объяснять что такое tdd :)

Comment: @PashaPash, там это второе предложение. Я понял его понял, как "TDD загнулось так же, как средства визуального проектирования"... Теперь понял, что имелось в виду :) Всё равно TDD в том виде, который он предполагает, никем не используется. Все предпочитают говорить о TDD в контексте наличия тестов.

Answer (score 0):

Как показала практика чего захочет пользователь/заказчик потом - не реально. Максимально предугадать помогает только хорошее знание компонента, как части  продукта (проекта), и опыт его использования (или подобных). И при всем при этом может подойти дядя сверху и сказать "хочу что бы оно крутилось тут, а там не крутилось"...

В компоненты обычно закладывается требуемый на данный момент функционал, с учетом его дальнейшего расширения или наследования.

Comment: А иногда и без, если команда разработчиков выбрала KISS как принцип работы. Пишется ровно то, что есть в ТЗ, без предположений о том, что оно куда-то будет расползаться.